# How to achieve this requirement using XLOOKUP in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup

My requirement is quite straightforward.
I have "Col A" -> Sheet1 that has the entries which are say our reference point
I am matching these entries to ColA in Sheet2
I want the entries in Sheet1 -> ColB to match Sheet2 -> ColB

I have three simple requirements

1. If the entry matches, display the value in Sheet1 -> ColB
2. If the entry does not match, display "ERROR" in Sheet1 -> ColB
3. If the entry matches is the entry is blank, then print blank (else it displays 0) in Sheet1 -> ColB

If I add this it takes care of requirement #1 and #2
`=IF(XLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:B)="","",XLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:B))`

If I add this, it takes of requirement #3 but Excel reports it as an "Inconsistent formula" . How do resolve this ?
`=IF(XLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:B,"ERROR")="","",XLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:B,"ERROR"))`

Worth pointing out that I have tried other functions like "`ISBLANK`" etc but they have all resulted in an error.

Comment: [This might help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fix-an-inconsistent-formula-5dd940a1-4f87-44bd-91dd-bf45ed828f05)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- <s>Your formulas don't match your description. They contain references to two sheets: `Sheet2` and `Test`.</s>
- The last formula contains a reference to `A1` and `A230`.
- Your formula logic currently is: If the result of the `XLOOKUP` is `""`, then return `""`, otherwise return the result of the second  `XLOOKUP`, which seems convoluted.

My guess as to your intent:

```
=LET(x,XLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:B,"ERROR"),IF(x=0,"",x))
```

Comment: BigBen same behaviour with the "let" function. It works but Excel reports it as an "Inconsistent formula".

Comment: That's not an error though.

Comment: If you don't want excel to flag inconsistent formulas, you can change the setting in Options > Formulas >Formulas inconsistent with other formulas in the region